# Remove focus from element in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to remove focus from  a particular element whenever it get focussed and pass the focus to its child element . I need to do this with angularJS alone ,no jQuery can be used . 
I have seen use of directive to set focus and ng-focus too. But didn't find anything to remove focus from an already focussed element .

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated

Comment: Have a look at ng-blur

Comment: @Gregg , I need to first check if the element is focused and then I needs to remove the focus. If I am not wrong ng-blur is to triggered when focus leaves the element ,

Comment: Ah, yes, agreed. Since jquery is not an option; how about jquery lite (angular.element) which is part of angular?

Comment: Assuming your element has class 'foo' angular.element(document.querySelectorall('.foo')).triggerHandler('blur');

Comment: Does anyone else find it ridiculous that a directive is needed just to remove focus from an element?

Answer (score -1):

I achieved this using a custom directive , which removes tabIndex from element and add it to its child.

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('nofocus', function($timeout) {
  return {
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $timeout(function() {
        element.removeAttr("tabindex");
        element.child().prop('tabIndex', 0);
      })
    }
  };
});
```